# Removing and re-adding series while keeping the same markers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to have my series redraw with the initial draw animation, to accomplish this I'm changing the "show()" method for my series to something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                }
            },
            series: {
                events: {
                    show: function () {
                        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                        var options = this.options;
                        options.color = this.color;
                        options.index = this.index;
                        options.data.marker = this.options.data.marker;
                        this.remove();
                        chart.addSeries(options);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

But of course I don't want to get a random marker every time I re-add the series to the chart. My issue arises when I try and access the marker from the series I'm removing and setting it in the options for my new series.

Does anybody know of a way to do this without breaking the current functionality? I'd like to generate the markers whenever I first draw the chart, but keep the same markers for the same series in the chart when I re-add it. I've managed to do it with the color and index of the series but nothing I try with the marker seems to work.

Here's my Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ax3o8uf3/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store `symbol` property. For example:

```
options.marker.symbol = this.symbol;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ax3o8uf3/22/